# Django Join three models

Tags: django

My model has these tables :

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
  user=models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=128,verbose_name=_('stockname'))
  number=models.CharField(max_length=64,verbose_name=_('number'))
  suffix=models.CharField(max_length=12,verbose_name=_('uffix'))
  brand=models.CharField(max_length=64, ,verbose_name=_('brand'))

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
  user=models.OneToOneField(User)
  tel = models.CharField(max_length=17,blank=True,verbose_name=_('tel'))
  address=models.CharField(max_length=264,verbose_name=_('address'))
```

and thoe third table is default User model which has relation to UserProfileInfo and Stocks

I have a table in my template like this :

```
{% for item in allstocks %}

<tr  data-original-title="888"  data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{ ??? obj.address ??? }}">
           <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.user }}</td>
             <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
             <td>{{ item.brand }}</td>
             <td>{{ item.number }}</td>
             <td>{{ item.suffix }}</td>

         </tr>
```

I think I should join those three tables to be able to show the address of the user in the mouseover tooltip of the HTML table, if so, How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a related name on your profile model

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
  user=models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

Then, when a user has an associated profile, you can access the profile model by `user.profile`

You could therefore access this in your template like

```
{{ item.user.profile.address }}
```

Or consider making your `Stock.user` (or make a `user_profile`) field be a foreign key to `UserProfileInfo` instead of `User`.